# Using List from Method in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, event-log

I am trying to parse an event log file into a `dataGridView` in `Windows Forms`. 
I am using the `EventLogEntry` class to do so, but have run into a problem I need to get the parsed log that I have cast to a list out of the method it is in and put as the `dataSource` for the `dataGridView` in the program.

> I need to use the List `_LogEntries' outside the method it is
>   contained in. I do not know how to do this

```
public static class parser
{
    public static string evlLocation = "%Program Files (x86)%\\EventLogParser\\ImportedEventLogs\\" + varBank.logInput;
    public static string evlLocationManual = "K:\\Event Log\\Test\\BSN_Navigator.evt";

    public static void ReadEventLog()
    {
        EventLog eventLog = new EventLog(evlLocationManual);
        EventLogEntryCollection eventLogEntries = eventLog.Entries;
        int eventLogEntryCount = eventLogEntries.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < eventLogEntries.Count; i++)
        {
            EventLogEntry entry = eventLog.Entries[i];
            //Do Some processing on the entry
        }
        List<EventLogEntry> _LogEntries = eventLogEntries.Cast<EventLogEntry>().ToList();
    }
}
```

Below is the code from the `MainForm.cs` for `Windows Forms`

```
    private List<Foo> ComputerName = new List<Foo>();
    private List<Foo> EventId = new List<Foo>();
    private List<Foo> EventType = new List<Foo>();
    private List<Foo> SourceName = new List<Foo>();
    private List<Foo> Message = new List<Foo>();

    class Foo : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string bar_;
        public string Bar
        {
            get { return bar_; }
            set
            {
                bar_ = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Bar");
            }
        }

        public Foo(string bar)
        {
            this.Bar = bar;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return bar_;
        }
    }

    // Bind the dataset to the grid.
    private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var bs = new BindingSource(ds, "Events");
        Foo foo1 = new Foo("someStuff");
        ComputerName.Add(foo1);

        bs.DataSource = parser._LogEntries;
        //Bind fooList to the dataGridView
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
        //I can see bar1 in the listbox as expected

        this.Invoke(pbHandler, new object[] { 100, 100 });
    }
```

Comment: You have run into a problem? Please elaborate. What problem have you run into?

Comment: I need to  use the List `_LogEntries' outside the method it is contained in. I do not know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

In the comment you said:

> I need to use the List `_LogEntries' outside the method it is contained in.

You simply need a property in your class like below:

```
public static class parser
{
    public static string evlLocation = "%Program Files (x86)%\\EventLogParser\\ImportedEventLogs\\" + varBank.logInput;
    public static string evlLocationManual = "K:\\Event Log\\Test\\BSN_Navigator.evt";

    public static void ReadEventLog()
    {
        EventLog eventLog = new EventLog(evlLocationManual);
        EventLogEntryCollection eventLogEntries = eventLog.Entries;
        int eventLogEntryCount = eventLogEntries.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < eventLogEntries.Count; i++)
        {
            EventLogEntry entry = eventLog.Entries[i];
            //Do Some processing on the entry
        }
        LogEntries = eventLogEntries.Cast<EventLogEntry>().ToList();
    }

    public static List<EventLogEntry> LogEntries {get; private set;}
}
```